# Log file monitoring until specific string is found in a log file

Tags: python, jython

I would like to monitor a log file until specific string is found in the file using Jython

Sample code:

```
import codecs

import sys 

import time

cnt = True

while cnt:

if 'User TechAdmin is logged out' in open('<File path>/Log_File_Test.log').read():

if 'ERROR' in open('<File path>/Log_File_Test.log').read():

  raise StandardError ("Error Found in File - Please refer log")

else:

  read_f = ''

  cnt = False

else:

  time.sleep(3)
```

Code should monitor a file until it finds "User TechAdmin is logged out". If found, then I would like check whether the string "Error" exist in file. If Error found, raise exception and close the file.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of the code you posted. Also, tell us what is not working with your current code (e.g. show us the error messages if you receive any) and what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! As it stands, it is very difficult for us to help you. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read up on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and then edit the question accordingly. If you are asking us to debug your code, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); ensure you have sample inputs, outputs, and, if any, errors included. Cheers.